# How to update a Collectionview custom cell properties on UIViewController

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

My custom cell has image property.

```
class AODCameraCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, NibReusable {

@IBOutlet weak var lblCount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgAddCamera: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewMain: AODView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgBattery: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgWifi: UIImageView!
```

on my viewcontroller

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewCameraCollection: UICollectionView!
...
//Setup camera collection
viewCameraCollection.register(cellType: AODCameraCollectionViewCell.self)
viewCameraCollection.delegate =  self
viewCameraCollection.dataSource = self
```

and on CollectionView data source i have this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: AODCameraCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
    cell.lblCount.isHidden = true
    let c = viewModel.cameras[indexPath.row]

    if viewModel.currentMode == .multi {
        Logger.i("Showing for index: \(indexPath.row)")
        if cell.player == nil, let l = c.link {
            let player = playVideo(inView: cell.viewMain, withURL: l)
            viewModel.setMediaPlayer(forKey: c.id, withPlayer: player)
            cell.player = player
            cell.viewType = .preview
        } else if c.feedFromPhone {
            cell.viewType = .phoneCamera
            let feed = AODCameraFeedView(frame: .zero)
            feed.delegate = self
            viewCameraFeed = feed
            cell.viewMain.addSubview(feed)
            feed.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
                maker.edges.equalToSuperview()
            }
        } else if c.link == nil  && !c.feedFromPhone{
            cell.viewType = .empty
        }
    }


    return cell
}
```

Is there a way i can access my custom cell image properties, change it and then update the cell without adding a new cell?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just reload the collection view based on your requirment.

ex:-

```
 @objc func reloadCollectionViewAction(sender: UIButton!) {

 DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self. viewCameraCollection.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CellForItemAtIndexPath function and specify the index of the cell you want to access. You can then update all the members of that particular cell. After updating, just reload the collectionView.

Comment: Thanks arun :). I found my answer a little later after i've posted my question thanks!